# how to get daily results of a formula for 5 years and put them in a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

My table records dates for various actions for a quantity of projects. Each project (2000+) has:

- 3 possible events: initiation, completion, cancellation
- 2 possible statuses: on, off.

I would like to report on the exact number of "on" project for every date since 2015.

I wrote a formula to determine, for one date, the amount of "on" projects.

=IF(OR(AND(L5<>"";$O$2C5); AND(L5="";$O$2<=J5;$O$2>=C5); AND($O$2>C5;J5="";C5<>"")); "on"; "off")

The date is in cell O2 and there is a simple countif function that gets me the count of "on" projects.

Now, I would like to  know if there is a way to collect the ~2000 results for that countif function for each date.

Ideally I would get a table with

```
A               B
dates:          number of ongoing projects
1/1/15          15
1/2/15          12
1/3/15          32
...             ...
10/22/19        63
```

so I can make a graph with it.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT 2 MOCKUP

Realised there were problems in my mockup data, please find the chart there:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10E9jX1Qlq-KQLCHupci3_8MiP7p5l-f2J1M5yFtfjQ0/edit#gid=1817091281

EDIT 3: definition of an 'ON' project

a project is on if:

```
final date <> "" AND initial date <= date checked <= final date,
OR
cancel date <> "" AND initial date <= date checked <= cancel date
OR
final date ="" AND cancel date = "" AND initial date <= date checked
```

I think all of them are mutually exclusive so maybe I can make 3 countifs and sum them? Would that work? I don't have time now but I'll try during my lunch break.

EDIT

[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcKvI.png)

I hid all the unnecessary columns. This is excel on mac but the original data is on excel for PC.

Comment: what version of excel are you using? have you ever used `Power Query` or `Power BI`?

Comment: I am using the most recent version of excel. I have never used Power Query or Power BI, no

Comment: One screenshot will help us too much.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego sorry about that -- I included a screenshot now.

Comment: can you use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a table of mocked up data so others can easily regenerate your case and come up a solution? Also do you have any idea about what kind of chart you want to create? This may give additional requirements to the data layout.

Comment: @TerryW Hi Terry! I entered the data for 10 lines: the result for this count is: 3 as lines 6, 7 and 9 (with titles 5, 7 and 8) are "on". Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TerryW About the chart I want, I am really not sure for now.

Comment: @TerryW I added EDIT 3 for the conditions to define an ON project, does this help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution:

I have 3 mutually exclusive situations where a project is ongoing:

```
final date <> "" AND initial date <= date checked <= final date,
OR
cancel date <> "" AND initial date <= date checked <= cancel date
OR
final date ="" AND cancel date = "" AND initial date <= date checked
```

So I intertwined 3 countifs together to make it work:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$20,"<="&O2,$J$2:$J$20,">="&O2,$J$2:$J$20,"<>"&""),COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$20,"<="&$O2,$L$2:$L$20,">="&$O2,$L$2:$L$20,"<>"&""),COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$20,"<="&$O2,$L$2:$L$20,"="&"",$J$2:$J$20,"="&""))
```

Thank you to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`=COUNTIFS(C2:C1048575,"<" & $O2,J2:J1048575,">" & $O2,L2:L1048575,">")`

That function will count just in case column the date requested on `O2` is bigger than the values on column C and if the date on `O2` is smaller than the values on column J and if the date on `O2` is smaller than the values on column L (so even if the project was cancelled, it was running at that time.

Anyhow, if one of the conditions should be modified, just change ranges or conditions (maybe >=...)

When the formula works just copy and drag down and it will do the same issue for all the dates on column O.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi David, thank you for this idea! countifs seems like the way to go however I have a problem: this ignores all the lines where I have no finalization date as we need to be > initiation and < finalization. is there a way to mix in some "OR" functions in the criteria maybe?

Comment: Hi David, I added EDIT 3, can you give me your thoughts? Thank you!